# Xcode 4 component orientation problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, orientation, landscape

I'm using xCode 4 for my project which should work both on iPad and iPhone. So, i have created Universal windows based application. I want my application starts into landscape mode so i added following:
in method:

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

I set `interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`
and added the key into `application.plist:
 Initial Interface Orientation` and set it on Landscape (right home button).

Now, the application did start in landscape mode, however, every component in it (button, label) remains rotated 90 degrees (counterclockwise).
When i load xib, Window orientation is set into Portrait and dropdown is disabled. 
anybody has idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` isn't asking you to set the variable (and will have no way of reading the result even if you do), it's a query as to whether the nominated orientation is acceptable. So you want:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
                                    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) return YES;
    return NO;
}

/* or: return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; */
```

The XIB is a separate issue; neither Interface Builder nor its replacement parts in Xcode 4 can see what you're doing in your code, so they shouldn't just decline to let you design in landscape mode. However, it's the view that is linked to the view member of the relevant UIViewController that you want to set the orientation on, not the window.